# apps updates not working: itunes continues to ask me for the password

Tags: macos, updates, macos-catalina

after updating the mac to Catalina, I am not able to update the apps anymore, because iTunes continues to ask me for the password.

This is what I tried:

- logout from iCloud from system preferences and reboot
- rename the folder Library/Keychains/xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx and reboot

Answer (score 0):

There is no more iTunes in Catalina. I've upgraded and saw that iTunes went away.
Can you verify if it is a message from iCloud or AppleStore?
You may find some other recommendations in [techradar](https://www.techradar.com/au/how-to/macos-catalina-problems-how-to-fix-the-most-common-issues)

Comment: you are right, but when I try to update the apps a modal window appears with this message: "login to iTunes stores". I continue to login but the modal window continues to appear and I can not update apps.

Comment: Ok I understand. So I think this must be such a sort of garbage let by catalina's update, you should use a tool like Titanium Onyx, to clean your system, I think it could helps.